# Checking if image properly loaded with Qunit

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, qunit

I'm trying to validate image `URLs` with `Qunit` by setting the URL as the `src` attribute of a test image and checking with the `error` event handler whether that went well. So far what I have is:

```
test('image',function() {
    var test_image = $('#test-image');
    test_image.error(function(e) { // properly triggered
        console.log(e);             
        is_valid = false;
        // ok(false,'Issue loading image'); breaks qunit
    });
    var is_valid = true;
    test_image.attr('src','doesntexist');
    console.log('checking is_valid');  // occurs before error event handler
    if (is_valid) {  // therefore always evaluates to the same
        ok(true,'Image properly loaded');
    } else {
        ok(false,'Issue loading image');
    }
});
```

My problem is that although the `error` event is properly triggered, it seems to occur in an asynchronous fashion and after the evaluation of `is_valid` (therefore whatever check I make, the result will always be the same). I have tried adding the `ok()` assertion inside the `error` event handler, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: ok() assertion outside test context
```

**How can I run an assertion based on the processing performed inside the `error` event handler?**

PS: if I insert a `alert('test');` before checking `is_valid` it works fine (which confirms problem with error handler being asynchronous) but as you can imagine is not acceptable. I tried using `setTimeout` to delay execution of if statement but it brings the same assertion  context error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By quickly looking through QUnit API, I see that you should use [`asyncTest`](http://api.qunitjs.com/asyncTest/) function for this. Before setting the src-attribute for your `test_image`, hook a function to [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event. Here's an untested code:

```
asyncTest('image',function() {
    var test_image = $('#test-image');
    test_image.error(function(e) {
        console.log(e);             
        ok(false,'Issue loading image');
        start();
    });
    test_image.load(function() {
        ok(true,'Image properly loaded');
        start();
    });
    test_image.attr('src','doesntexist');
});
```

Comment: It works, what a miss on `asyncTest` :(. Btw, `onload` should be replaced by `load` as we're dealing with a `jquery` object there for which `onload` is not defined.

Comment: Nice catch, didn't think it through. I edited my answer to use [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).